# Azure monitoring solution

Tags: azure

I have azure log analytics workspace configured on my resource group.

I want monitoring dashboard for my resources(storage,sqldb,dw etc) individually.

May I know what tools from the marketplace for azure monitoring solution to be selected? I don't want every resources to be configured manually. I want the basic monitoring only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have `Azure Monitoring` as the defacto solution on Azure cloud for metric tracking for resource usage and utilization measurement. Of course, you can then build a custom metric measurement solution by augmenting this by extending data from `Azure Monitoring` and streaming this to `ELK stack using Fluentd` or even plan for an enterprise integration to SIEM solutions using platforms such as `Splunk`

Please be more descriptive and direct in your ask and improve your question.